# Click thru rate (CTR) and Open Rate on Gmail

Tags: email, click, analytics, tracking, email-analytics

I am a product owner on a project and am attempting to track the following metrics for email:

1- Number of times email has been opened “O”
   Open / Sent = Open Rate

2 - Number of times email link(s) have been clicked 
   Clicks / Open = Click-through Rate

We will be sending these emails thru our custom built platform and need to track these metrics and was told by our dev team that we cannot track images or scripts sent to Gmail.

Questions:

3 - Is that true? can we not track thru Gmail?

4 - Is there a workaround?

Thank you in advance for any response on this.

Shawn

Answer (score 0):

3: yes
4: no

You can only detect when someone clicks your link.